# Divi: how to hide/show specific menu according current page?

Tags: customization

I use Divi plugin.

I have these menu items:

- Blog
- Enterprise
- Coach
- Help

On my home page, I have these 4 items: OK
When I click on "Entreprise" item (to show enterprise page), I want to hide automatically "Blog" item into toolbar menu. And of course if I come back on home page, I want to show "Blog" item.

How can I do that please?

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to your `functions.php`:

```php
function hide_menu_items( $items ) {
    if ( is_page( 'Enterprise' ) ) { // You can use page ID, slug or title here
        foreach ($items as $key => $item) if ( $item->title == "Blog" ) unset( $items[$key] );
    }
    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', 'hide_menu_items', 20 );
```